# Media queries don't work on Android and iPhone

Tags: mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm trying to make a website responsive and looking good on smartphones and tablets.

Here's a link to this website: http://fineart.d.dev.vendo.no/

The problem is that my mobile devices don't see a media queries I wrote specifically for them.
I know that this question is really often asked here on Stackoverflow but I didn't found any solution for this problem. Here's my code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    /* Some mobile-specific code goes here */
}
```

I tried to use `max-device-width` and added

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

to the  section but without success :(

Could you please help me to solve this issue? I realy stuck with it and need your help.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not seeing the viewport meta tag in the head of the page -- am I missing something?

Comment: Thank you David. It's strange... I can see < meta name="viewport"> in Developer tools but it's not present in source code... Maybe this is because I'm adding the <viewport> with JS? If so could you please tell me ho to fix it? I have not access to the whole page, only to 2 files attached at the bottom of the head section: lifevision.css and lifevision.js. Thank you!

Comment: Via developer tools, what's the line number for the viewport tag? Maybe I need to change my coffee :)

Comment: :) Just after <meta name="robots">. Please see a screenshot: http://www.mediafire.com/view/wlmq2qmpw7xwpbi/fineart-dev-tools.jpg

Comment: It's added with JS. David, could you please tell me do you see 2 attached files at the bottom of the page: lifevision.js and lifevision.css? I just noticed that I can see them on Chrome but not Firefox :( It's very strange... I'm going crazy...

Comment: Sorry, it seems that I needed to add some special parameter into website's address to make this scripts loaded. Arghhh... :) Thank you for help everybody and especially you David! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using this meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Having "maximum-scale=1" will prevent users from scrolling, which is commonly seen as an accessibility problem. Let a user zoom if they need to.

As for the media queries, I looked at your CSS, but I didn't actually see any media queries present. Are you sure that the CSS file with those queries loading?

Comment: Thank you for advice, I'll experiment with it. Media queries are presented in "lifevision.css" file, at the bottom of the page. I tried to use max-device-width instead of max-width but this rule was ignored both by browser and smartphone. So I turned back to the max-width.